# How to select date today from each day that has in between date?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem about the data that I want to display. Basically I have this table.

**history_table:**

```
| history_date_from | history_date_to |
+-----------------+---------------+
| 2019-10-12      | 2019-10-12    |
| 2019-10-25      | 2019-10-28    |
| 2019-11-18      | 2019-11-22    |
| 2019-11-19      | 2019-11-25    |
| 2019-11-20      | 2019-11-20    |
```

The problem that I'm having is what if today is already `2019-11-19`. I still want to show the third row until `2019-11-22`.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT history_date_from,history_date_to
FROM history_table
WHERE DATE(history_date_from)= CURDATE() BETWEEN DATE(history_date_from) AND DATE(history_date_to)
```

But the problem from my query is it will just depend on the `CURDATE` of the `history_date_from`, what I'm trying to achieve is to still get the third row for tomorrow until the end of the date depends on the `history_date_to`.

So if today `2019-11-19` the output should be:

```
| history_date_from | history_date_to |
| 2019-11-18      | 2019-11-22    |
| 2019-11-19      | 2019-11-25    |
```

because the `history_date_to` is still not done in terms of date.

Any help would be really appreciated, I think I'm just making thing complicated with my query.

Comment: `= =CURDATE()` ??

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry. my mistake.

Comment: Given that today is '2019-11-22' (where did the time go?) what should the desired result look like? Edit your question accordingly. Also DATE() is redundant in this instance,

Comment: @Strawberry hi , sorry for the confusion. i edited my post. thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM history_table
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN history_date_from AND history_date_to
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7911dc71cf5817f6ee275d889e16ea25)

You don't need to check for the exact match on `history_date_from`. You want to know if the current date is in a specific period of time. So `BETWEEN` is a good way to go.

Comment: omg!!! why i didn't thought of this! thank you so much, sorry my bad.